# Maximum of an integral that depends on a parameter

Tags: numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization

I have defined a function f(x,t) :

```
f[x_, t_] := 
NIntegrate[
  1/Sqrt[k^2 + 100] Exp[-I Sqrt[k^2 + 100] Exp[x] Cosh[t] + 
     I k Exp[x] Cosh[t] - I Log[(Sqrt[k^2 + 100] + k)/(Sqrt[k^2 + 100] - k)]],
 {k, -10, 10}]
```

Plotting it was not a problem (using Abs), but I was trying to get a better picture of it by looking for its maximum value, I couldn't obtain a result defining this function (it seems that to do the integral Mathematica requires a value for x and t):

```
g[t_] := MaxValue[Abs[f[x, t]], x]
```

Mathematica gave me results when I used:

```
FindMaximum[Abs[f[x, 4]], {x, -8}]
```

for particular values of t, but with errors. Is there a proper or better way to find the maximum of Abs[f] with respect to x for each value of t ? I thought of making a list (discretizing x and t), but maybe there are existing solutions inside Mathematica to deal with this sort of problems.

Comment: Define `f` using `f[x_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ]`.

Comment: @march : What is the reason to put ?NumericQ after the arguments?

Comment: It forces *Mathematica* to evaluate the function *only* when the arguments to the function are numbers.

Comment: @march But isn't there a way to make something like g(t) = MaxValue[f(x,t),x] ?

Comment: `g[t_?NumericQ] := First@FindMaximum[Abs[f[x, t]], {x, -8}]`.